# sql join two table replace null value to first table value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database.

table1

```
name    id
atc51   5
atc52   6
atc53   7
atc54   8
```

table2

```
name    bbbb
atc51   0
atc52   0
atc52   1
atc53   0
atc53   1
atc54   0
atc54   1
atc54   2
```

At the moment I am only selecting join.I'm trying to join both tables and have the following result

```
name    id  bbbb
atc51   5   0
atc52   6   0
atc52   6   1
atc53   7   0
atc53   7   1
atc54   8   0
atc54   8   1
atc54   8   2
```

Comment: mysql, oracle and plsql are all different databases, which one are you using. Also, what have you tried already, where are you stuck? Also, i can't see any null values in your table that you've given us.

Comment: my db MYSQL Database

Comment: What means *replace null value to first table value* ? Please shouw your SQL statement

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

Use inner join: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1384f3/1

```
select table2.name,table1.id,table2.boob from table2 inner join table1
on table2.name=table1.name
```

Output:

```
name    id  boob
atc51   5   0
atc52   6   0
atc52   6   1
atc53   7   0
atc53   7   1
atc54   8   0
atc54   8   1
atc54   8   2
```

Comment: I've given fiddle link, you can check there and it should work definitely @mmsmsm